# Why the spellcheck is not working properly for .exs files?

Tags: spell-checking

```py
test "UD.1 should delete the given record" do
  [user, compnay ] = insert_record()
  asset = Asset |> last |> Repo.one
  {:ok, deleted} = Delete.delete(to_string(asset.id), user, company)
  assert asset.id == deleted.id
end
```

This is an `.exs` file. I have done `:set spell` and you can see the `UD` has a line under it.

In the second line, `compnay` is spelled incorrectly, however the spell checker is not picking it up. Why is that?

Do I need to install something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
  :syntax spell toplevel
```

Many file types define regions where spell checking takes place. This is usually comments and strings, leaving the rest of the code not spell checked. However, you can change this behavior by having vim spell check everything (called the toplevel syntax).